# How do you get Deno to use the DENO_AUTH_TOKENS environment variable?

Tags: deno

Using the `DENO_AUTH_TOKENS` environment variable doesn't appear to work for me. I've created a personal access token from GitHub and added it to my environment as described in the [private modules](https://deno.land/manual@v1.14.3/linking_to_external_code/private) page of the Deno manual. However, I still just get a 404 error:

```
error: Import 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/MYCOMPANY/MYREPO/main/MYFILE.ts' failed: 404 Not Found
```

I've verified that the token is in the environment variable, and it succeeds in curl by executing the following:

```
curl -s https://$DENO_AUTH_TOKENS/MYCOMPANY/MYREPO/main/MYFILE.ts
```

Am I doing the import differently than the Deno runtime expects it?

```js
import { foo } from 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/MYCOMPANY/MYREPO/main/MYFILE.ts';
```

Running the script with `-L debug` gives a lot of verbose logging, but nothing about tokens at all.

What does it want me to do?

```
$ deno --version
deno 1.14.2 (release, x86_64-apple-darwin)
v8 9.4.146.16
typescript 4.4.2
```

Answer (score 0):

This was a dumb mistake. When I added the variable to my .profile file, I forgot to add `export` before. It works after adding that:

```sh
export DENO_AUTH_TOKENS=aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa@raw.githubusercontent.com
```